# nmap says 0 hosts up even though I can ping

Tags: vmware, nmap

I'm running Metasploit from Win 7 x64, and I've set up my Metasploitable 2 virtual machine on VMware Player.  I can ping Metasploitable's IP address from the Metasploit console, however if I use nmap it says:

Note: Host seems down.  If it is really up, but blocking our ping probles, try -Pn

I try it with the -Pn switch, it says

Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 0.64 seconds

I've disabled my Windows firewall and I'm running Metasploit as admin.  Why can't I nmap my virtual machine?

Comment: Can you add the output (sanitized if you like) of `nmap --iflist` and `nmap --route-dst $TARGET` where `$TARGET` is the IP of the Metasploitable VM?

Comment: I don't know what the problem was, but it's definitely an issue with Windows. I installed Metasploit on a Backtrack VM and it works fine.

Comment: see also http://superuser.com/q/737431/4227

Answer (score 14):

Using `sudo` often fixes it: `sudo nmap [options]`

Nmap needs root to construct raw packets (it doesn't rely on the system's ping binary for pinging, but it also does a lot of other custom packet crafting). When Nmap is allowed this raw capability, a ping scan works as expected.

Protip: `sudo !!` repeats the last command as root (the `!!` stands for "last command").

Comment: Being `sudo` also works on my system, however, it's problematic because I execute `nmap` through a PHP script which by default does not have elevated rights :-(

Comment: It's odd to me because without using sudo nmap can discover other systems (well ... my router, and my current laptop computer) but not my windows 10 sbc (lattepanda).

Comment: unfortunately that did not work.... sudo nmap can't see what ping can (sierra macbook pinging a win10 lattepanda connected to same wifi router)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using an older (version 6.00 or 6.01) version of Nmap, this may be related to a [known bug](http://seclists.org/nmap-dev/2012/q3/23). Try running with `--unprivileged`, which will break some features of Nmap, but ought to work for port scanning. Alternatively, use the output of `nmap --iflist` to identify the interface name (e.g. `eth1`) that should be used for the scan, and pass it to Nmap with the `-e` flag, like so: `nmap -e eth1 --other --args targets`

Of course the best solution is to [upgrade to an unaffected version of Nmap](https://nmap.org/download.html) with the latest improvements.

Comment: Your solution works on windows with nmap 7.70, which is much later than the buggy versions you listed. It might be a good idea to test `-e` no matter which version you are using.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem in my Windows 7 Enterprise x86.

When I added the `-e` option as [bonsaiviking](https://superuser.com/users/127590/bonsaiviking) explained, it works well, though too slow. Additionally, I found it happens when your PC has multiple network adapters such as VM network (VMware Network Adapter VMnet8).

After disabling the `vm8` adapter it works well without the `-e` option.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with nmap 7.92 on Windows 11, and installing npcap resolved the issue for me.